# Google Photos 'Search People' Feature & Changing The Default Photo Assigned

Tags: google-photos

Need help, Google Photos has enabled search photos by people in my account. Problem is, I want to change the default photo used to label by family members and friends? How do I change the default photo that Google Photos has assigned?

Comment: This would be better suited for http://webapps.stackexchange.com/  I asked the same question at the Google forum: [How can we change the default thumbnail picture for someone in the "people" section?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/photos/zNDye75jNcI;context-place=forum/photos)